# MVVMCross How does this View get linked to the ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to figure out why I get an error message about not being able to find the right ViewModel when I'm running my iOS app.

The question I have is when I look at this [example](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Working%20With%20Collections/Collections.Touch/Views/MainMenuView.cs) I don't understand where MainMenuView gets bound to MainMenuViewModel.

Can someone answer this for me?

Thanks,

PkL728

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are bound by class names: for XXXView should be corresponded XXXViewModel

Comment: So in my iOS project I have a ProductsView class which extends MvxTableViewController and in my core project I have a ProductsViewModel class.  When I run my program I get this error:  Failed to load ViewModel for type LoginProductsMVVM.Core.ViewModels.ProductsViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator... Do I have this set up wrong?

Comment: Ok... so my error was related to a method being called in my ProductsViewModel constructor that was erroring out.  Not a helpful error message!!  Thanks Roman!

Comment: Make sure you have trace turned on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233922/mvvmcross-mvx-trace-usage/17234083#17234083 - then you'll see more of the 'not helpful' error message.

Comment: OMG. Wasted 2 days due to this.

Comment: Name convention is the default setting. There are several ways to override it: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/Customizing-using-App-and-Setup#overriding-view-viewmodel-associations

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to the answer: double-check the names of the views after renaming (even Resharper renaming is not perfect). Spent several dozens of minutes (and a beer can), catching  similar MvvmCross's error `Could not find view for %ViewModelName%`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this on a project that I've just upgraded to MvvmCross 4. I don't have much experience with MvvmCross, and the project hasn't been maintained for a few years, so it's possible something else is wrong.

I ended up hard coding the mappings in Setup::InitializeViewLookup because I don't have time to waste on it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who ends up here having the same problem I had. I was getting this error in an Android project because my (properly named) view was extending Activity and not MvxActivity (happens easily when you use Xamarin Studio's "Add Android Activity" feature)